# Run android emulator or sandbox on mobile itself

Tags: java, android, emulation, sandbox

Is there any tool out which runs an apk on a real mobile device, like an emulator. The tool would need to execute the apk properly, but also be able to intercept certain commands. Any chance?

To make it more clear, I dont need a shell command to start and stop or so. I need more of a container emulator like tool, which might be able to inject/alter running compiled code.

Comment: Can you make it more clear?, you need to debug an application on the device?

Comment: no, I dont need to debug it. Actually I need to run it, intercept commands and eventually inject content.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but I don't understand how running the emulator on your phone magically makes all of that easy when compared to running the emulator on your computer.

Comment: I did not ask for an "easy" way, I have to run it on the phone, no where else, thats my projects requirements

Answer (score 0):

The ADB connects to running devices, those are:
Running emulators;
Devices connected trough USB that have "Developer options on"+"USB debugging" on device enabled

Also, you need to accept in the device the key for debugging trough ADB after connecting.

Obs: Drivers may be necessary for the device, (google has a package in SDK manager with Google Drivers that works for some devices too)